# How to select seperate string values from an array and use them as column names in a pandas dataframe Python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have following array containing string values:

```
type(array)
pandas.core.indexes.base.Index

print(array)
Index(['hooiland_1_1', 'hooiland_1_2', 'hooiland_1_3', 'hooiland_1_4',
       'roggeteelt_1_1', 'roggeteelt_1_2', 'roggeteelt_1_3', 'roggeteelt_1_4',
       'zwartebraak_1_1', 'zwartebraak_1_2', 'zwartebraak_1_3',
       'zwartebraak_1_4', 'hooiland_2_1', 'hooiland_2_2', 'hooiland_2_3',
       'hooiland_2_4', 'roggeteelt_2_1', 'roggeteelt_2_2', 'roggeteelt_2_3',
       'roggeteelt_2_4', 'zwartebraak_2_1', 'zwartebraak_2_2',
       'zwartebraak_2_3', 'zwartebraak_2_4'],
      dtype='object')
```

I want to use each of this string values of this array as a separate column name in an empty pandas dataframe.

tried:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=["class",array]) ###first column is "class"
gives error: Invalid syntax
```

Also tried to split the array but without success:

```
array.split()
gives error :AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

**Expected output:**
dataframe:

```
class    hooiland_1_1    hooiland_1_2    hooiland_1_3 .... zwartebraak_2_4
class1   value           value           value             value
class2
class3
```

I add the values later on the process but I first need to construct the empty dataframe with the correct column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=["class"] + array.tolist())
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want. Thanks. Check out other answers for alternatives to your method.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Index.insert`

```
idx_arr = idx_arr.insert(0, 'class')

Out[444]:
Index(['class', 'hooiland_1_1', 'hooiland_1_2', 'hooiland_1_3', 'hooiland_1_4',
       'roggeteelt_1_1', 'roggeteelt_1_2', 'roggeteelt_1_3', 'roggeteelt_1_4',
       'zwartebraak_1_1', 'zwartebraak_1_2', 'zwartebraak_1_3',
       'zwartebraak_1_4', 'hooiland_2_1', 'hooiland_2_2', 'hooiland_2_3',
       'hooiland_2_4', 'roggeteelt_2_1', 'roggeteelt_2_2', 'roggeteelt_2_3',
       'roggeteelt_2_4', 'zwartebraak_2_1', 'zwartebraak_2_2',
       'zwartebraak_2_3', 'zwartebraak_2_4'],
      dtype='object')

pd.DataFrame(columns=idx_arr)

Out[447]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [class, hooiland_1_1, hooiland_1_2, hooiland_1_3, hooiland_1_4, roggete
elt_1_1, roggeteelt_1_2, roggeteelt_1_3, roggeteelt_1_4, zwartebraak_1_1, zwarte
braak_1_2, zwartebraak_1_3, zwartebraak_1_4, hooiland_2_1, hooiland_2_2, hooilan
d_2_3, hooiland_2_4, roggeteelt_2_1, roggeteelt_2_2, roggeteelt_2_3, roggeteelt_
2_4, zwartebraak_2_1, zwartebraak_2_2, zwartebraak_2_3, zwartebraak_2_4]
Index: []
```

Comment: I'm now using ```pd.DataFrame(columns=["class"] + array.tolist())``` suggest here as an answer by Sunil Goyal, but your code also works! Thanks from providing an alternative

Answer (score 1):

Your code `pd.DataFrame(columns=["class",array])` doesn't generate a list and hence the invalid syntax.

If you want to add "class" to the beginning of the index, you could try:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=array.insert(0, 'class'))  # adding 'class' to the beginning of the index
```

Btw you may want to avoid using `array` as your variable name...

Comment: I'm now using ```pd.DataFrame(columns=["class"] + array.tolist())``` suggest here as an answer by Sunil  Goyal, but your code also works! Thanks from providing an alternative. Note: I'm not using the name ```array``` in my code but did it here for clarity.